# how to avoid deadlock in spring data neo4j ogm while saving data concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I have been trying to load test concurrently using SpringDataNeo4j(SDN) with 1 CPU AND 1GB RAM.
For 'GET' (read) request able to test 1000 threads with ramp-up of 1second.
For 'POST' (write) request, but able to test only with 18 threads with ramp-up of 1second, beyond this thread. We face DeadLock exception:

> Caused by: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error executing Cypher "Neo.TransientError.Transaction.DeadlockDetected"; Code: Neo.TransientError.Transaction.DeadlockDetected; Description: LockClient[1081] can't wait on resource RWLock[NODE(97), hash=108078135] since => LockClient[1081] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[NODE(98), hash=1267379687] <-[:WAITING_FOR]- LockClient[1076] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[NODE(97), hash=108078135]

I have referred
http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#transactions-deadlocks

```
TransactionTemplate template = new TransactionTemplate(  ).retries( 5 ).backoff( 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
```

For saveService, I use default `@Transactional` though I couldn't able to replicate the `TransactionTemplate` in my testing code. And I use my DataSourceFactory configuration.

```
@Configuration 
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:ogm.properties" }
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.my.graph.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
```

Any suggestions!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what is the Cypher-syntax you are using in the write tests ?

Comment: I was not using cypher in this context. I am using OGM 'Dao.save(node)' where API extends GraphRepository

Answer (score 4):

You can reduce the possibility of a deadlock happening by

- making the transaction smaller - e.g. instead of saving 1000 nodes and relationships, save only 100
- using the structure of your domain ensure that you don't concurrently update same nodes

But sometimes it is not possible to avoid. In those situations you can either

- catch the exception and rerun the transaction (essentially do yourself retry)

  ```
  int retries = 5;
  while (retries > 0) {
    try {
      fooService.foo(bar);
    } catch (CypherException ex) {
      retries--;
      Thread.sleep(delay);
    }
  }
  ```
- use some library that already implements retry logic, like [spring-retry](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry) or [guava-retrying](https://github.com/rholder/guava-retrying)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will start implementing the same.

Comment: I have implemented a custom retry mechanism for node save as you suggested, I found some improvements. Thought not consistent always. Deadlock remains with less requests